# Check if an Excel object is not themed

Tags: excel, vba

If I read the ThemeColor of a Border from an Excel FormatCondition it gives me an error

> 'Application-defined or object-defined error'

in the watch list, or

> Run-time error 5: 'Invalid procedure call or argument'

when reading in the Immediate window. Other times it is just Null. The error seems to arise when there is an actual valid border set.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.border.themecolor I get the following

> Attempting to access a theme color for an object whose color is not
>   currently themed will result in an invalid request run-time error.

Other objects I am checking also have a similar issue, eg the `.Interior.ThemeColor`.

**How can I tell if an object is themed - is there an official way to do so? Can I use the fact that there is an error to infer that it is not themed, or can errors arise for other reasons?**

Some example code:

```
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim fcs As FormatConditions
Dim cf1 As FormatCondition
Dim b1 As Border

Set WS = ActiveSheet
Set fcs = WS.Cells.FormatConditions
Set cf1 = fcs.item(1)
Set b1 = cf1.Borders.item(xlEdgeBottom)

Dim tc As Variant
tc = b1.ThemeColor            'error
tc = cf1.Interior.ThemeColor  'error
```

To reproduce, create an Excel Sheet with a conditional format rule. The rules I am using are using a formula, eg =NOT(ISNUMBER(C9)), and impose a cell fill colour and sometimes a border on the bottom of the cell, and cover a range of cells, eg $C$8:$C$39

Comment: You also have to wonder about `cf1.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.item(i).ThemeColor` (where i is a valid index)

Comment: And `cf1.font.ThemeColor`, and `cf2.Interior.PatternThemeColor`. The two I mention in the original question are the ones that have actively given me problems, but it's likely that that these others could under the right circumstances

Answer (score 0):

This **doesn't answer directly whether a cell is themed**, but instead handles [*Run-time error '5'*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/invalid-procedure-call-or-argument-error-5)*: Invalid procedure call or argument* directly in context with addressing a potentially themed object in a typical way of [error handling in VBA](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/#Runtime_Errors). So instead of just

```
something.ThemeColor   ' access any theme-property
```

you could follow this basic structure in your Sub

```
Sub ThemeTest()
    Dim isThemed As Boolean: isThemed = True
    On Error GoTo notThemedError
    something.ThemeColor   ' access any theme-property; jumps to notThemedError on error
    On Error GoTo 0        ' reset error handling to normal
    If isThemed Then do_something Else do_other
    ... more code
    Exit Sub

notThemedError:
    ' Optionally re-raise the error if it's not Error 5
    If Not Err.Number = 5 Then Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description
    isThemed = False
    Resume Next  ' go on after where the error was raised
End Sub
```